# Counter vector shows non binary output upon simulation

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I have filtered out many errors already and my code is now simulating properly according to the testbench. The problem however is that if you look at the simulation output of the reg_counter vector it is showing very strange non-numeric outputs, which is not supposed to have since it is a counter. Yet each element of the vector is a normal binary number. How do i fix this?

Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity encoder_control is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC;
           A2 : in STD_LOGIC; --inverse signal
           B : in STD_LOGIC;
           B2 : in STD_LOGIC; --inverse signal
           I : in STD_LOGIC;
           I2 : in STD_LOGIC; --inverse signal
           Error : out STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           Sys_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           Dir :out STD_LOGIC;
           reg_counter : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0):= (others => '0'));
end encoder_control;

architecture Behavioral of encoder_control is
type state_type is (ST0,ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4);
signal PS,NS: state_type;
signal counter: integer:= 0;
begin

comb_proc: process(PS,A,B,Sys_clk,Reset)
begin
if (Reset = '1') then
PS <= ST0;
counter <= 0;
Error <= '0';
Dir <= '0';  --check if reset active
elsif(rising_edge(Sys_clk))then --if no reset then PS is NS on clock pulse
    PS <= NS; --else needed
case PS is  --state machine 
    when ST0 => 
        if(A = '0' and B = '0') Or (A2 = '1' and B2 = '1') then
            counter <= counter+1;
            Dir <= '1';
            NS <= ST1;
             elsif(A = '1' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '0') then
                counter <= counter -1;
                Dir <= '0';
                NS <= ST3;
             elsif(A = '1' and B = '0') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '1')then
                NS <= ST4;
             else NS <= ST0;
                counter <= counter;
        end if;
    when ST1 => 
        if(A = '1' and B = '0') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '1')then
            counter <= counter+1;
            Dir <= '1';
            NS <= ST2;
             elsif(A = '0' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '1' and B2 = '0')then
                counter <= counter -1;
                Dir <= '0';
                NS <= ST0;
                --revolution -1?
             elsif(A = '1' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '0')then
                NS <= ST4;
             else NS <= ST1;
                counter <= counter;
        end if;    
   when ST2 => 
        if(A = '1' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '0')then
            counter <= counter+1;
            Dir <= '1';
            NS <= ST3;
             elsif(A = '0' and B = '0') Or (A2 = '1' and B2 = '1')then
                counter <= counter -1;
                Dir <= '0';
                NS <= ST1;
             elsif(A = '0' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '1' and B2 = '0')then
                NS <= ST4;
             else NS <= ST2;
                counter <= counter;
        end if;
  when ST3 => 
        if(A = '0' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '1' and B2 = '0')then
            counter <= counter+1;
            Dir <= '1';
            NS <= ST0;
            --revolution +1
             elsif(A = '1' and B = '0') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '1')then
                counter <= counter -1;
                Dir <= '0';
                NS <= ST2;
             elsif(A = '1' and B = '1') Or (A2 = '0' and B2 = '0')then
                NS <= ST4;
             else NS <= ST3;
                counter <= counter;
        end if;
   when ST4 => 
        counter <= 0;
        Error <= '1';
   when others => 
   counter <= 0;
   NS <= ST0;
end case;
end if;
--reg_counter <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(counter, reg_counter'length)); --convert integer to vector
end process comb_proc;

reg_counter <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(counter, reg_counter'length)); --convert integer to vector
 end Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity Encoder_test1 is
end Encoder_test1;

architecture Behavioral of Encoder_test1 is
signal A : STD_LOGIC;
signal A2 : STD_LOGIC;
signal B : STD_LOGIC;
signal B2 : STD_LOGIC;
signal I : STD_LOGIC;
signal I2 : STD_LOGIC;
signal Reset : STD_LOGIC;
signal Error : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal Dir : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal Sys_clk : STD_LOGIC;
signal reg_counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0):= (others => '0');
COMPONENT encoder_control
Port(
A : IN STD_LOGIC;
A2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
B : IN STD_LOGIC;
B2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
I : IN STD_LOGIC;
I2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
Reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
Error : OUT STD_LOGIC;
Dir : OUT STD_LOGIC;
Sys_clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
reg_counter : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
END component;
begin
i1: encoder_control
PORT MAP(
A => A,
A2 => A2,
B => B,
B2 => B2,
I => I,
I2 => I2,
Reset => Reset,
Error => Error,
Dir => Dir,
Sys_clk => Sys_clk,
reg_counter => reg_counter);

t_prcs_A: process
begin
loop
A <= '0';
wait for 25000 ps;
A <= '1';
wait for 50000ps;
A <= '0';
wait for 25000 ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_A;

t_prcs_A2: process
begin
loop
A2 <= '1';
wait for 25000 ps;
A2 <= '0';
wait for 50000ps;
A2 <= '1';
wait for 25000ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_A2;

t_prcs_B: process
begin
loop
B <= '0';
wait for 50000 ps;
B <= '1';
wait for 50000ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_B;

t_prcs_B2: process
begin
loop
B2 <= '1';
wait for 50000 ps;
B2 <= '0';
wait for 50000ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_B2;

t_prcs_I: process
begin
loop
I <= '0';
wait for 25000 ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_I;

t_prcs_I2: process
begin
loop
I2 <= '1';
wait for 25000 ps;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_I2;

t_prcs_Reset: process
begin
loop
--Reset <= '1';
--wait for 5000 ps;
Reset <= '0';
wait;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_Reset;

t_prcs_Sys_clk: process
begin
loop
Sys_clk <= '0';
wait for 5000 ps;
Sys_clk <= '1';
wait for 5000ps;
--if(now >= 1000000 ps) then wait; end if;
end loop;
end process t_prcs_Sys_clk;
end Behavioral;
```

Simulation output:

[image: Simulation output]

Comment: You can right-click on reg_counter -> radix -> unsigned decimal to see your result as decimal value

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to "fix" with the reg_counter output. The value shown in your simulation (0083f64c) is just a number (8648268) written down in the hexadecimal system. It's basically the same like writing down a number in the binary system (for example 5 is "0101" in binary) but here in base 16 instead of base 2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

If you still want to display the decimal number there is probably some option for that in the simulation tool (not sure which one you are using).